# How do I parse argparse arguments into a list of strings, stopping on a predefined flag argument?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

How can I parse variable length argument lists delimited by special predefined syntax. An example:

```
   ./script --arg1 --cmdname otherscript --a1 --a2 --cmdname-- --arg3
```

After parsing with `argparse` script should have three arguments: `arg1`, `cmdname`, `arg3`. The argument `cmdname` should consist of a list of three values `otherscript`, `a1`, `a2`.

Having such a recipe would be useful to be able to pass on everything in `cmdname` into a `subprocess.popen(cmdname, ...)` call.

I was thinking about subparsers. But I believe a subparser cannot be stopped, and really is mutually exclusive with other subparsers. Any other easy, already provided way? Is subclassing the `Action` the way to do it?

Comment: Would this alternative syntax suffice? `./script --arg1 --cmdname "otherscript --a1 --a2" --arg3`

Comment: @unutbu -- That's a really good suggestion.  Pair that with `shlex.split` and I think you'd be in business.

Comment: @unutbu and @mgilson: Good points! Wasn't aware of `shlex.split()`. The syntax I suggested is more appealing in terms of shell quoting and escaping: It is just much easier to pass subcommands with their arguments if you do not have to worry about quotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you indicated in your post, subclassing `Action` is probably the way to do this -- Although that gets pretty tricky if the arguments to `otherscript` aren't known by argparse.  You might be able to get around this with `parse_known_args`, but you might not.  Honestly, I really think the easiest way is to preprocess `sys.argv` yourself.

```
import shlex
s = shlex.split("./script --arg1 --cmdname otherscript --a1 --a2 --cmdname-- --arg3")
def preprocess(lst):
    """
    process an iterable into 2 lists.
    The second list contains the portion bracketed by '--cmdname' and '--cmdname--'
    whereas the first portion contains the rest of it.
    """
    argv1,argv2 = [],[]
    current = argv1
    for i in lst:
        if i == '--cmdname':
           current = argv2
        elif i == '--cmdname--':
           current = argv1
        else:
           current.append(i)
    return argv1,argv2

l1,l2 = preprocess(s)
print l1
print l2
```

And an alternative implementation of `preprocess` which works for sliceable objects that have a `.index` method -- `sys.argv` would work just fine:

```
def preprocess(lst):
    """
    process an iterable into 2 lists.
    The second list contains the portion bracketed by '--cmdname' and '--cmdname--'
    whereas the first portion contains the rest of it.
    """
    try:
        i1 = lst.index('--cmdname')
        i2 = lst.index('--cmdname--')
        argv1 = lst[i1+1:i2]
        argv2 = lst[:i1]+lst[i2+1:]
    except ValueError:
        argv1 = lst
        argv2 = []

    return argv1,argv2
```

---

Another option (pointed out in an excellent comment by @unutbu) is to change the commandline syntax to something a little more standard which simplifies the problem greatly:

```
./script --arg1 --cmd "otherscript --a1 --a2" --arg3
```

Then you can parse `cmd` as you normally would using `argparse` (specify `type=shlex.split` for this argument to convert from a string to a list of arguments).

Comment: That's a good pragmatic approach. This could be combined with passing on `l1` into `argparse.parse_args()`. I'd prefer an integrated argparse solution though. I am not fixated on the exact `--cmdname--` stop flag. I guess `++cmdname` or maybe even `--cmdname` again would be ok if that helps to stay within the argparse realm.

Comment: @cfi -- Yes, I was assuming you would pass `l1` to `parser.parse_args()`.  I really don't see how you'll do better than the suggestion by unutbu though if you want to stay completely within argparse (at least, if you don't want to dig through the internals and rely on a bunch of implementation details).  The problem is that argparse will interpret `--a1` as an argument and it will either use the associated action, or complain that it doesn't know what to do with that argument.

Comment: Solves the problem -> Accepted. Although if someone can come up with an integrated argparse solution I'd prefer that for clarity, ease of use and possibly the auto-usage --help generation.

Comment: Looked into subclassing. Would have to rip apart even `_parse_known_args` and modify couple of other places. `argparse` does not provide interfaces for subclassing/changing the tokenizer while maintaining a consistent behaviour (help page!). Time's limited for this project so I have to move on. Thanks to both of you @unutbu and @mgilson!

Comment: Please rename `IndexError` into `ValueError` which is thrown by `str.index()` (Python 3.2.2 here)

Comment: @cfi -- You're right.  I was positive that should be an `IndexError`.  Updated.

Comment: *grin* I mix them up all the time, and just am happy if others do so, too. Says a lot about myself, now, doesn't it? However an `index` function throwing a `value` error when there would be `index` errors available, too, is mean by design ;-)

Answer (score 3):

It would help argparse if we distinguish arguments that begin with `--` from parts of the command which also begin with `--`.

So if `./script ++arg1 ++cmdname otherscript --a1 --a2 ++arg3`
is acceptable, then:

```
import argparse
import shlex

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prefix_chars = '+')
parser.add_argument('++arg1', action = 'store_true')
parser.add_argument('++arg3', action = 'store_true')
parser.add_argument('++cmdname', nargs = '*')
args = parser.parse_args(shlex.split("++arg1 ++cmdname otherscript --a1 --a2 ++arg3")) 
print(args)
```

yields

```
Namespace(arg1=True, arg3=True, cmdname=['otherscript', '--a1', '--a2'])
```

Comment: Clever.  +1 for this answer and (more importantly for your previous comment which I still believe is the best way to do this)

Comment: @mgilson: Yes, that is the way other commands like `bash -c "..."` work, so it is probably the most familiar to programmer/users.

Comment: I suppose the downside to this approach is if `otherscript` uses `+` as it's "prefix_chars" as well.  That's pretty rare though so it should be pretty safe.

Comment: @unutbu: Unfortunately @mgilson's previous comment is the limiting factor of this approach. While I generally agree to clear separation of concepts, the `otherscript` with its options is beyond my control and some of the scripts I plan to support do have a very mixed syntax. In fact, they use the same trick for yet more subcommands. The beauty of this approach is that this can be nested and mixed once the parser is written. The other scripts use perl (and their own parsers, no std modules) so I can't copy&paste, though ;-)